# SQL Removing duplicates one row at a time

Tags: php, sql, mysql, duplicates

I have a table where I save all row-changes that have ever occurred. The problem is that in the beginning of the application there was a bug that made a bunch of copies of every row.

The table looks something like this:

```
copies
|ID |CID |DATA
| 1 | 1  |  DA
| 2 | 2  |  DO
| 2 | 3  |  DO (copy of CID 2)
| 1 | 4  |  DA (copy of CID 1)
| 2 | 5  |  DA
| 1 | 6  |  DA (copy of CID 1)
| 2 | 7  |  DO
```

CID is UNIQUE in table copies.

What I want is to remove all the duplicates of DATA GROUP BY ID that is after one another sorted by CID.

As you can see in the table, CID 2 and 3 are the same and they are after one another. I would want to remove CID 3. The same with CID 4 and CID 6; they have no ID 1 between them and are copies of CID 1.

After duplicates removal, I would like the table to look like this:

```
copies
|ID |CID |DATA
| 1 | 1  |  DA
| 2 | 2  |  DO
| 2 | 5  |  DA
| 2 | 7  |  DO
```

Any suggestions? :)

I think my question was badly asked because the answer everybody seems to think is the best gives this result:

```
ID   | DATA | DATA | DATA | DATA | DATA |     DATA |        CID          |
                                                   |Expected |  Quassnoi |
1809 |    1 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 |     NULL |  252227 |    252227 |
1809 |    1 |    0 |    1 |    1 |    0 |     NULL |  381530 |    381530 |
1809 |    1 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 |     NULL |  438158 | (missing) |
1809 |    1 |    0 |    1 |    0 | 1535 | 20090113 |  581418 |    581418 |
1809 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    0 | 1535 | 20090113 |  581421 |    581421 |
```

CID 252227 AND CID 438158 are duplicates but because CID 381530 comes between them; I want to keep this one. It's only duplicates that are directly after one another when ordering by CID and ID.

Comment: In your final resultset, `(2, 2)` and `(2, 7)` don't have `id 1` between them either. Does it mean they should be deleted as well? If not, what distinguishes them?

Comment: They dont have ID 1 between them but they have (2, 5, DA).

ID should be ignored as "duplicate" data, it should be used to group the rows together. It may have been distracting to talk about two IDs. 

If you look at the last table you see only one ID and the expected result from just that ID.

Comment: `(1, 1)` and `(1, 4)` have a `DO` between them. Why do you want `(1, 4)` to be deleted then?

Comment: If you take the sequence (ascending order of CID) of entries with ID = 1, you have: (1, 1, DA), (1, 4, DA), (1, 6, DA). Since the ID and DATA values in these rows are the same, only keep the first of the 'duplicate'. Similarly, for ID = 2 the sequence is: (2, 2, DO), (2, 3, DO), (2, 5, DA), (2, 7, DA). The ID and DATA values in the rows with CID = 3 and CID = 2 are the same and CID = 3 should be removed; the row with CID = 5 has a different value in DATA (compared with CID = 2) and should be ke[t, and the row with CID = 7 has a different value in DATA compared with CID = 5 and should be kept.

Comment: Quassnoi: Because the "DO" is not from the same ID. The query should always group by ID.

Comment: See the post update based of `@Jonathan Leffler`'s explanations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DELETE   c.*
FROM     copies c
JOIN     (
         SELECT  id, data, MIN(copies) AS minc
         FROM    copies
         GROUP BY
                 id, data
         ) q
ON       c.id = q.id
         AND c.data = q.data
         AND c.cid <> q.minc
```

**Update:**

```
DELETE  c.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  cid
        FROM    (
                SELECT  cid,
                        COALESCE(data1 = @data1 AND data2 = @data2, FALSE) AS dup,
                        @data1 := data1,
                        @data2 := data2
                FROM    (
                        SELECT  @data1 := NULL,
                                @data2 := NULL
                        ) vars, copies ci
                ORDER BY
                        id, cid
                ) qi
        WHERE   dup
        ) q
JOIN    copies c
ON      c.cid = q.cid
```

This solution empoys `MySQL` session variables.

There is a pure `ANSI` solution that would use `NOT EXISTS`, however, it would be slow due to the way `MySQL` optimizer works (it won't use `range` access method in a correlated subquery).

See this article in my blog for performance details for quite a close task:

- [**`MySQL`: difference between sets**](http://explainextended.com/2009/08/19/mysql-difference-between-sets/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this deletes:
| 2 | 7  |  DO

Its not all rows that are the same that should be deleted just the ones that comes directly after oneanother grouped by ID.

Comment: To do this properly, you also have to have a criterion that there is no row with a different data value and the same ID value and with a CID between the 'current row' and the 'earlier row with the same data value'.  That's fiddly, at best.

Comment: Hi Quassnoi, i've tried thisone and it deletes nearly everything i have in the table. How should the query look like if i have more then one DATA columns?

Comment: Nice, thank you very much Quassnoi. At a first glance it seems to get it right. I will run some tests to verify!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `count` in a subquery for this:

```
delete from copies
where
    (select count(*) from copies s where s.id = copies.id 
                                   and s.data = copies.data 
                                   and s.cid > copies.cid) > 0
```

Comment: I don't think this works correctly at all.  It doesn't take into account whether or not the DATA value between successive rows ordered by ID and CID.

Comment: It actually does. I just mislabeled `data` as `name`. My bad. Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

```
// EDITED for @Jonathan Leffler comment
//$sql = "SELECT ID,CID,DATA FROM copies ORDER BY CID, ID";
$sql = "SELECT ID,CID,DATA FROM copies ORDER BY ID, CID";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link); 
$data = "";
$id = "";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){ 
       if (($row[0]!=$id) && ($row[2]!=$data) && ($id!="")){
            $sql2 = "DELETE FROM copies WHERE CID=".$row[1];
            $res = mysql_query($sql2, $link); 
       }
       $id=$row[0];
       $data=$row[2];
}
```

Comment: Really? You've got three pure SQL approaches here, and you're suggesting using an interpreted language kicking off single `delete` transactions? I sincerely hope that's not how you solve all of your database problems. Databases are about thinking in sets!

Comment: 1º is for the consultation is a process at once. 2º there is a PHP tag, so it's okay to include a solution with this language. something else?

Comment: @Eric the task has to be done once for cleanup purposes, so I'd think that speed isn't a primary concern here.  That makes it a valid answer, if not the best answer.

Comment: 1º?  2º?  What are the degree marks for?  (I don't mean that to be snide...is that the way that some languages write ordinal numbers?)

Comment: @andres: I think your cursor-based solution is likely to be the best way to do this (of those shown so far) - but I would expect to order the data with 'ORDER BY ID, CID'.  See also my comment to the main question.

Comment: @Beska: yes, 1º is equivalent to 'first' in some languages.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, yes, by analyzing the code, the correct order would "ID, CID, thanks

Answer (score 0):

delete from copies c where c.cid in (select max(cid) as max_cid, count(*) as num from copies where num > 1 group by id, data)

Comment: This will only delete the last duplicate, not all duplicates.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but you can run query again until all duplicates are deleted. Your solution is more elegant (I already voted your answer)!